# In verilog how we can use real number

Tags: floating-point, verilog, fft, fpga, xilinx

In verilog how we can use real number(for example-  input data at testbench code for ip core(floating point))
In testbench how we can add these numbers???

Answer (score -1):

The `real` type in Verilog is equivalent to 64bit floats (ie doubles). They are typically not synthesizable but should work for testbenches; you should be able to use typical operations on them such as addition:

```
real x, y, z;

initial begin
  ...
  z = x + y;
end
```

Comment: I put real but it appeared undefined in the simulation

Comment: xn_re = 110011110111.101100110010011;
xn_im = 101110111001.10110011010011 ;

Comment: I used it at FFT ip core - input data at testbench code for ip core(floating point)). In testbench how we can add these numbers???

Comment: I used it at FFT ip core - input data at testbench code for ip core(floating point)). In testbench how we can add these numbers???

Comment: If you need to use a `real` as an input to a module, you'll need to use `$realtobits` to convert it. Without your code, it's impossible to know why it was undefined. Note also that `real` is 64 bits, if you need 32 bit floats, it's best to use `shortreal` in SystemVerilog; or there are ways to approximate 32-bit floating point with 64-bit so long as you stay in the smaller range.

Comment: I worked with Verilog (ISE14.5) not SystemVerilog.

Comment: I added the problem here- https://support.xilinx.com/s/question/0D54U00005TFlTDSA1/in-verilog-how-we-can-use-real-numberfor-example-input-data-at-testbench-code-for-ip-corefloating-point-in-testbench-how-we-can-add-these-numbers

Comment: In Verilog, literals with a decimal point (such as `111.10101010011110000111`) are always treated as base 10 numbers, so they are being fed into what are essentially 32-bit unsigned integer so are truncated. In the case of `110011110111.101100110010011`, this cannot be represented in 32-bits and so is both truncated after the decimal point and all binary digits above the 32nd. However, since these are not in floating point format in the `xn_re` and `xn_im`, Im sure the IP core is not able to process them. You need to convert them into floating point form before passing them into the IP core.

Comment: What might be the easiest way to do this if you still want to be able to operate on the numbers in the testbench separately would be to use `real`; use `$realtobits` to get doubles as bits, then convert the doubles to floats manually by dropping bits from the melissa and adjusting the exponent manually for each number. This can add error to the calculations but you can try to mitigate it but picking inputs that can be perfectly represented by floating point numbers and being careful with the math do you in your testbench on the doubles (or tolerating some error in checking values)

Comment: Otherwise, you either need to move to SystemVerilog and use `shortreal` (to note, the last version of Verilog was 2005, so over 15 years ago; SystemVerilog has replaced it; and ISE14.5 is almost 10 years old so if you can upgrade to Vivado, that would be a good idea); or you can do the operations independently in a separate program to generate the expected results for given inputs and not do any math in the testbench itself.

Comment: I still have a question, please
Is there a way to show output with a comma?
How will I know where the floating point is? thanks

Comment: I have Vivado but my old laptop the program stumbles and becomes very slow
So I try to use ISE but I didn't succeed :'(